# Missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed in min function

Tags: r

Question 1. Write a function called `my_min()` that computes the minimum of a numeric vector without the min() function. Include a logical argument called na.rm that specifies whether to remove NAs.

```
my_min <- function(x){
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
      if (x[i] < x[i+1]) {
        result <- x[i]
      } else {
        result <- x[i+1]
      }
  }
result
}

my_min(1:10)
```

> Error in if (x[i] < x[i + 1]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I don't know why there is a  missing value; can someone teach me how to do it with an `if` statement? (even if it does not need it, I just want to know the correct way to answer this question with an `if` statement).

Comment: hint: what happens on the last time through the loop when `i==length(x)` (in your particular example, when `i==10` )?

Comment: Gotcha, so it's like there is no x[11]. But as I change the i range into 1:(length(x)-1), it returns the output to be 9...

Comment: because in every round your x[i] is less than x[i+1],so in every iterator x  is updating.thats why you got the result as 9 in final rounf comparing 9 < 10

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
my_min <- function(x){
  min <- x[1]
  for (i in 1:(length(x)-1)) {
    now <- x[i+1]
    is.rm <- is.na(now)
    if ((now < min) & !is.rm) {
       min <- now
    } 
  }
  min
}
```

Comment: Ah got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, just a stupid question, where should I add "na.rm=TRUE" in this case? With it in the if() statement followed by a &&, it does not work when I try to run a vector containing NA, but out of the if() statement it shows missing value again

Comment: you can use is.na function to check NA values.i have updated the answer

Comment: kk ty so much!!